# Connect bluetooth with getRemoteDevice() from BluetoothAdapter

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I would like to manually connect a bluetooth device with its MAC address because it is faster and I know exactly which MAC to connect.

I use this method to get the BluetoothDevice : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getRemoteDevice%28byte[]%29

But the Android doc does not say if Android ensure that the device is in range before creating the BluetoothDevice object. 
Do you have this information ?

My code can automatically connect the device, and I would like to check if the target is in range before trying to connect, but without perform a large scan (which can be long...)

Answer (score 0):

When local device connects to remote device using `BluetoothSocket`, an exception is required.

If remote device isn't in range, It's not found

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean isSecure, UUID sharedUUID) throws IncorrectSetupException {
        try {
            //Secure connections requires to get paired before connect
            //Insecure connections allows to connect without pairing
            if (isSecure) {
                mSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(sharedUUID);
            } else {
                mSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(sharedUUID);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Is there some problem with the setup?
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            mSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //If device is not found, this exception is throwed
        }
    }

}
```